# Unable bind for the same port in PHP server socket programming

Tags: php, sockets

I am trying to bind socket with same port, I am getting error.

> socket_bind(): unable to bind address [0]: Only one usage of each
>   socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\my\server.php on line 79
>   Could not bind to socket

Here is 79-th line:

```
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that there is not something else already bound to that port

Comment: yes, i was run a program with a port, after some time i stopped that program. then run again the program, this time iam getting error, unable to bind.

Comment: Seems your first program hasn't exited properly and the port is still bound

Comment: Yes, My first program is not exited completely. I am reading socket in a while, if i stopped the execution that program isnt exited completely. How to close while loop if there is no incoming data from Client?

Comment: do
{
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
flush(); @ob_flush();
}
while ($input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n"));

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to bind socket with same port

Use a different port or kill the application that is bound to the port you are trying to bind to. Generally speaking only 1 application can be bound to a port at a time.

`netstat -O` is used to find ports that are in use via cmd in windows.

Comment: Yes, My first program is not exited completely. I am reading socket in a while, if i stopped the execution that program isnt exited completely. How to close while loop if there is no incoming data from Client?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You can bind only **one** socket to a tuple protocol/network address/port.
For example, you can't bind two TCP sockets on the port 4242.

Comment: Yes, My first program is not exited completely. I am reading socket in a while, if i stopped the execution that program isnt exited completely. How to close while loop if there is no incoming data from Client?